# For /R loop to create folders sans infinite nesting

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, recursion, cmd

I have a series of folders and subfolders that looks like this:

```
C:\Images\Annie\2016-09-09_Annie_PC\
C:\Images\Bill\2016-09-06_Bill_PC\
C:\Images\Charlie\2016-08-29_Charlie_PC\
```

The dated folders (such as 2016-09-09_Annie_PC) should contain several .CR2 files.

I want to use FOR /R looping to enter only the dated folders and create three subfolders (CR2S, DNGS, JPEGS), followed by moving the .CR2 files from the dated folder into the CR2S folder.

The folder tree should look something like this:

```
C:\Images\Annie\2016-09-09_Annie_PC\CR2S\ (containing .CR2 files)
C:\Images\Annie\2016-09-09_Annie_PC\DNGS\
C:\Images\Annie\2016-09-09_Annie_PC\JPEGS\
C:\Images\Bill\2016-09-06_Bill_PC\CR2S\ (containing .CR2 files)
C:\Images\Bill\2016-09-06_Bill_PC\DNGS\
C:\Images\Bill\2016-09-06_Bill_PC\JPEGS\
C:\Images\Charlie\2016-08-29_Charlie_PC\CR2S\ (containing .CR2 files)
C:\Images\Charlie\2016-08-29_Charlie_PC\DNGS\
C:\Images\Charlie\2016-08-29_Charlie_PC\JPEGS\
```

I've tried the below batch file, which creates infinite nested CR2S folders

```
for /r %a in (.) do @if exist "%%~fa\*.cr2" echo %%~fa & mkdir "%%~fa\CR2S" & mkdir "%%~fa\DNGS" & mkdir "%%~fa\JPEGS" & move "%%~fa\*.CR2" "%%~fa\CR2S\"
```

The output of the above code resembles:

```
C:\Images\Annie\2016-09-01_Annie_PC\CR2S\CR2S\CR2S\CR2S\CR2S\CR2S\CR2S\CR2S\CR2S\CR2S\CR2S\CR2S\CR2S\CR2S\31234100514197.CR2
```

How can I have the .CR2 files moved into a CR2S folder without the production of nested CR2S subfolders?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about, but it does not seem to be related to the "R" corresponding the the [tag:r] tag you added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that while you were recursively iterating on a folder, if the files were found, you were modifying the folder contents on the fly (by creating the new *CR2S* folder and moving the files inside), so the `for` loop was picking up the new folder as well and it was repeating the same operation forever (infinite recursion). That usually stops when *StackOverflow* occurs, but now

> The filename or extension is too long.

is occurring sooner.

This approach uses a recursive function (label) that handles the subdfolders first (so the new subfolders are created and files are copied when returning back from the stack), so the same infinite recursion problem is not encountered anymore.

*Notes*:

- I didn't create the *JPEGS* and *DNGS* (or should it be *PNGS* ?) folders since I didn't find them relevant (check the remark (`rem`) in the code).
- Every time you run the script it will move the files into an additional *CR2S* subfolder. Not valid anymore: check *@EDIT0*.

Here's the code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set _CR2SDIR=CR2S
set _ROOTDIR="."

call :handle_folder %_ROOTDIR%
goto :eof

:handle_folder
    for /f %%f in ('dir /b /a:d "%~1"') do (
        if "%%f" neq "!_CR2SDIR!" (
            call :handle_folder "%~1\%%f"
        )
    )
    if exist "%~1\*.cr2" (
        if not exist "%~1\!_CR2SDIR!" (
            mkdir "%~1\!_CR2SDIR!"
        )
        rem If needed, do the same for the other 2 subfolders
        move "%~1\*.cr2" "%~1\!_CR2SDIR!"
    )
    goto :eof

:: Old code; it won't be reached

for /r %%a in (.) do (
    if exist "%%~fa\*.txt" (
        echo %%~fa & mkdir "%%~fa\CR2S" & mkdir "%%~fa\DNGS" & mkdir "%%~fa\JPEGS" & move "%%~fa\*.txt" "%%~fa\CR2S\"
    )
)
```

**@EDIT0**: In order to address *Comment0* (not part of the initial request), I had to add an additional check in `:handle_folder`: if the subfolder's name is *CR2S*, then simply ignore it (I also did some *parameterization*). Note that there might be cases where this wouldn't be the expected behavior!

Comment: The script works, do you know of any way of modifying this script so that if it is ran more than once the .CR2 files won't be put into \CR2S\CR2S\...?
FYI .DNG files are like a camera's raw file.